# cloudformation post deployment script

Tags: javascript, npm, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I have an npm script called db:migrate that I want to run after every deployment on aws. That script runs a file called migrate.js (when present) which takes care of doing db migrations.

I'm using aws cloudformation for deployments, but I'm not sure what the best way is to have some form of post deployment script that would run that script: npm run db:migrate.

I thought there might be some form of cloudformation post deploy hook that I could use, but all I found are cloudformation custom resources. Apparently, I could trigger a lambda function after each deployment. The problem is that I don't know how I could access the ECS container from the lambda function in order to run the db:migrate script.

I'd appreciate any insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add userdata to your template (EC2/Launch Template/Launch Configuration)
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html

Comment: Can I use UserData with a fargate ECS Cluster?

Comment: Also, would using userdata run my npm command on every EC2 instance? What if I want to run it just once?

Comment: You can't use Userdata on fargate ECS Cluster cause with fargate you don't have access to server that your container is running on. You can use docker dedicated commands (CMD, ENTRYPOINT) to do whatever startup scripts your app requires.


Userdata will be run on every EC2 instance provisioned by ASG. It's up to you to implement script idempotency

Comment: Thing is, the script is not really related to the container or EC2 instance.. I dont need to run it for every EC2 instance.. I just need to run a post deployment script once.. Unfortunately it doest look like cloudformation has something like a post deployment hook I can use to run something just once.